# Oracle put resultset into variable in FORALL

Tags: oracle, collections, bulk, table-variable, forall

I have the following plsql block

```
declare 
    TYPE t_mds_ids IS TABLE OF mds.id%TYPE;
    l_mds_ids t_mds_ids;
    l_mds_parents t_mds_parents;
begin
    SELECT id BULK COLLECT INTO l_mds_ids FROM mds;
    FORALL indx IN l_mds_ids.FIRST .. l_mds_ids.LAST
        select l_mds_ids(indx), ch.id_employee_parent
        into l_mds_parents
        FROM hierarchy_all ch
        CONNECT BY ch.id_employee = prior ch.id_employee_parent
        START WITH ch.id_employee = l_mds_ids(indx);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate table mds_hierarchy_all';
    insert into mds_hierarchy_all
    select * from l_mds_parents;
end;
```

t_mds_parents declared as

```
create or replace type r_mds_parents as object (
  id_mds number(5,0),
  id_employee number(5,0)
);
/

create or replace type t_mds_parents as table of r_mds_parents;
/
```

And I get an exception ORA-00947: not enough values

I really need to put the resultset of multiple rows into variable of TABLE TYPE on each iteration of FORALL loop. I can't use BULK COLLECT into l_mds_parents as it's restricted inside of FORALL.
Is there only solution to use temporary table instead of table variable?

Comment: Plese, provide description of table mds_hierarchy_all. It looks like table mds_hierarchy_all doesn't have same count of columns like l_mds_parents

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with `forall`. You *could* use nested loops:

```
declare 
    TYPE t_mds_ids IS TABLE OF mds.id%TYPE;
    l_mds_ids t_mds_ids;
    l_mds_parents t_mds_parents;
begin
    SELECT id BULK COLLECT INTO l_mds_ids FROM mds;
    l_mds_parents := NEW t_mds_parents();
    FOR indx IN l_mds_ids.FIRST .. l_mds_ids.LAST LOOP
        FOR rec IN (
            select l_mds_ids(indx) as id_employee, ch.id_employee_parent
            FROM hierarchy_all ch
            CONNECT BY ch.id_employee = prior ch.id_employee_parent
            START WITH ch.id_employee = l_mds_ids(indx)
            ) LOOP
                l_mds_parents.extend();
                l_mds_parents(l_mds_parents.COUNT)
                    := NEW r_mds_parents (rec.id_employee, rec.id_employee_parent);
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate table mds_hierarchy_all';
    insert into mds_hierarchy_all
    select * from table(l_mds_parents);
end;
/
```

But you don't need to use PL/SQL at all; use a single hierarchical query, or probably more simply here, recursive subquery factoring:

```
insert into mds_hierarchy_all /* (id_mds, id_employee) -- better to list columns */
with rcte (id_mds, id_employee) as (
  select m.id, ha.id_employee_parent
  from mds m
  join hierarchy_all ha on ha.id_employee = m.id
  union all
  select r.id_mds, ha.id_employee_parent
  from rcte r
  join hierarchy_all ha on ha.id_employee = r.id_employee
)
select * from rcte;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2b14a851021555d0b2fcb78909efcfbe) with some made-up data.